# how to match the structures in C?

Tags: system-verilog

In SV,

```c
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} abc, abc1;
```

where the `abc` and `abc1` are matching type but the
`struct {int a; int b; } abc2; abc2` is not matching to `abc1`.

Why is it so, even though the members of the structures are same?

Answer (score 1):

The rules in section *6.22 Type compatibility* of the [1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595%5DIEEE) explain that anonymous types can only match:

> objects declared within the same declaration statement and no other
> data types

In general, SystemVerilog has a [strong typing policy](https://verificationacademy.com/resources/technical-papers/using-strong-types-in-your-systemverilog-design-and-verification) for unpacked structs. This means the criteria for matching types is the name alone and not by looking into the layout of the structure.